# Logitech usb wireless doesn't wake up computer from suspend

Tags: suspend, logitech-unifying

my usb wireless Logitech mouse is not able to wake up my computer (a laptop with the lid usually kept closed, so no access to the power button for resuming it).
Mouse is a Logitech M525, but the problem arise also with a M235 (all they have in common is using a "unifying" wireless receiver).
The BIOS "wake up from usb" option in the computer (a Dell Latitude E6520) is enabled.

Shouldn't easy?
I tried installing Solaar, but it just providing pairing and battery status functionalities.

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this w/ a udev rule. This is for 16.04 but I have used the same method for earlier versions. I have no clue if it will work for 18.04.

1) use lsusb to find the device ID for the receiver. I believe the ID for these devices is always 046d:c52b, but this could vary.

2) Put the following into a udev rule. The file I used is "90-keyboard-wakeup.rules":

SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d",ATTRS{idProduct}=="c52b",RUN+="/bin/sh 
-c 'echo enabled > /sys$env{DEVPATH}/../power/wakeup'"

3) Put e.g. 90-keyboard-wakeup.rules into /etc/udev/rules.d directory.

4) reboot.